# jQuery onclick with parameters gives "** is not defined"

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

This is in my Javascript:

```
function doSomething(fieldActions) {
var Actions = fieldActions;

$(Actions).show("slow");
$(this).hide(); }
```

This is in my HTML:

```
<a onclick="doSomething('#date-actions');">edit</a>
```

The parameter needs to affect and DIV field. The ID of this field can be variable and there can be multiple on a page, so that's why I need to give the specific field it affects on.
The parameter "#date-actions" is an example of what a DIV field could be called that it is calling to.

My error in firebug:

```
doSomething is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently wherever `doSomething` is defined it's not a globally accessible function, for example if it's inside a `document.ready` handler it's only accessible inside there.  You would need to expose the scope...but even then `this` wouldn't refer to what you wanted inside the function.

---

A better approach to solve both issues would be to use the `href` property of the link itself, like this:

```
 <a class="edit" href="#date-actions">edit</a>
```

Then by giving it a class, like in the above example, you can bind all those links on `document.ready` like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.edit").click(function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this.hash).show();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

If they're added dynamically just change the bind from `$("a.edit").click(function(e) {` to `$("a.edit").live("click", function(e) {`.

Comment: Thanks Nick. But what should I do if I have more parameters to pass?

Comment: @user260157 -Can you give an example? you can do `data-show="#thing1, #thing2, #thing3"` as a multiple selector, for example, and use `$($(this).attr("data-show")).show()` to use it.